# Vertical aligning of text within Draft JS editor

Tags: javascript, css, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

How can we vertically align text within a draftjs text editor? It should support **top, center and bottom alignments**.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible, you just need to write a custom component:

https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components